# How to efficiently extract coordinates from a `pybedtools.Interval`?

Tags: python, pybedtools

I'm using [pybedtools](https://daler.github.io/pybedtools) to process data, and at some point, I loop over a `BedTool` object and use [*unpacking*](http://treyhunner.com/2018/03/tuple-unpacking-improves-python-code-readability/) to extract coordinates from the `Interval`:

```
for interval in my_bedtool:
    (chrom, start, end, _, _, strand) = interval
```

Suppose I want to compute the interval length, as follows:

```
    length = end - start
```

This results in a `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'`.

It happens that the unpacked `end` and `start` variables are strings.
Converting them to ints is probably suboptimal given that `Interval`s can be created by providing ints for the coordinates:

```
from pybedtool import Interval
interval = Interval("X", 0, 100, strand="+")
```

The `start` and `end` attributes of an `Interval` are ints.

I could do:

```
    (chrom, start, end, strand) = (
        interval.chrom, interval.start, interval.end, interval.strand)
```

But I think this looks a bit ugly.

Is there a better approach?

Comment: i do not know `pybedtools` but `list(Interval("X", 0, 100, strand="+"))` >>> `['X', '0', '100', '.', '.', '+']`- shouldn't the conversion of integers to strings be considered a bug?

Comment: @Chris_Rands I was indeed surprised by this behaviour. As I say in my answer, I guess it might be related to how indexing works. It seems to rely on a string representation of the genomic interval: https://daler.github.io/pybedtools/intervals.html#indexing-into-interval-objects

Comment: I'm not sure, but the explanation of the behaviour could be found around these lines: https://github.com/daler/pybedtools/blob/master/pybedtools/cbedtools.pyx#L512

Comment: Or rather, this one: https://github.com/daler/pybedtools/blob/master/pybedtools/cbedtools.pyx#L256

Comment: Yes exactly, I was peaking at the same source code myself; so it's a design decision not a bug i guess, still seems odd to me (my guess is that keeping a homogenous list in terms of types might allow some performance benefits for cython)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why unpacking an `Interval` results in strings instead of ints might be related to how [indexing by position](https://daler.github.io/pybedtools/intervals.html#indexing-into-interval-objects) works.

Even without considering the string/int issue, it seems slightly more efficient to access the interval's attributes rather than unpacking them directly:

```
In [311]: %timeit [(chrom, start, end, strand) for (chrom, start, end, _, _, strand) in my_bedtool]
306 ms ± 26.7 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [312]: %timeit [(interval.chrom, interval.start, interval.end, interval.strand) for interval in my_bedtool]
238 ms ± 24.3 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

To resolve the ugliness issue, attribute access can be made more compact through the use of `operator.attrgetter`:

```
In [313]: from operator import attrgetter

In [314]: get_interval_attrs = attrgetter("chrom", "start", "stop", "strand")

In [315]: %timeit [get_interval_attrs(interval) for interval in my_bedtool]
239 ms ± 26.7 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Comment: FYI https://pastebin.com/3QBnVsKU